# Visual Studio Mac App Publishing (from archive) error: parameter name "key" cannot be null

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, app-store-connect, visual-studio-mac

I have some issue during the publishing of my first ios app from vs for mac!

Here are the steps that i've done to signing and (trying to) distributing the app:

1. Distribution Channel: App Store

[image]

2. Destination: upload on App Store Connect

[image]

3. Recap of distribution certificate and provisioning profile

[image]

4. Login with Apple Dev Account

[image]

5. App ready to publishing

[image]

6. The error: value cannot be null : parameter name key

[image]

Any idea?

ps: my entitlement.plist is empty...maybe i have to put some key there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using my apple account password in the image 4...but i had to use app password instead (generated from security setting of my apple account)...there was even written, but i didn't read before :D